# Asynchronous function ahead of setState

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I found solutions for functional programming, but I need solutions for programming in classes without use useEffect.
Code app:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: "hello"
    };
  }

  setText() {
    this.setState({
      text: "new text"
    });
    this.func();
  }

  async func() {
    console.log(this.state.text);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.setText.bind(this)}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In the console, I see "hello". How to execute setState first and then its asynchronous function?

Comment: Dear @Red, Welcome to Stack Overflow. +1 upvote for your motivation.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the `setState` function act asynchronous, so you should use the callback of `setState` for calling the `func` function:

```
setText() {
  this.setState(
    {
      text: "new text",
    }, 
    this.func // callback of setState
  );
}
```

Then in the console, you can see `new text`.

Comment: Dear @Red, is this answer your answer to settle the issue?!